# Managing AWS via Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm new to Python/Boto3.

I would like to manage AWS using python.

I'm unable to find details on all available python functions of methods to manage AWS.

Example:

```
import boto3

ebs=boto3.resource('ec2')
vols=ebs.volumes.all()
for vol in vols:
    print vol.id
```

The above code works well but I'm trying to understand what is **id** in 'vol.id 'is it attribute of vol ? and where to find all available attributes that are valid to go with 'print vol.*'

How do I know that in 'vols=ebs.volumes.all()' **all()** is valid to use with **volumes** and what other options are available ?

I have tried using boto3 documentation but struggling.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: How to get type hinting to work so I can see the available method calls and return types. I'm using PyCharm

Comment: You need to understand AWS services/infra to understand each Boto3 functionality.  For quick start, playing AWS CLI first before dig yourself into boto3 (when you have poor understanding of each parameters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like an instance id the Volumes also have identifiers, so this line "print vol.id" is printing the list of volume identifiers(since in a loop). You can use this ID to look for the volume.
For example in the console under EC2>> Volumes>> when to type the ID in search it provides you the volume  details.

all() -
as the doucmentation says "Creates an iterable  resources in the collection".
This is just getting the list of all available volumes corresponding to ebs(elastic block storage).
Another example :volume.snapshots.all()

This displays all the snapshots associated with a particular volume.

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print all attributes associated with vol, try these code

```
import boto3

ebs = boto3.resource('ec2')
vols = ebs.volumes.all()

for vol in vols:
    print vol.__dict__
```

This will print all the properties associated with volume.

Hope it helps !!

Comment: It worked for me. Think you forgot to mention you needed snapshot id's in question